# How to reset bootstrap multiselect dropdown angular 2

Tags: angular, bootstrap-multiselect

I am using bootstrap select plugin in angular 2 application (https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-select).

I am successfully able to create it. But I am facing issue to reset the filter values selected. I am running below code to do so:

```
this.filterForm.get('select').setValue([]);
(<any>$('#filter-dropdown')).multiselect('refresh');
this._ref.detectChanges();
```

Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong over here?

Comment: if you want to use bootstrap select try this:https://valor-software.com/ng2-select/ dont use jQuery with angular.

Answer (score 0):

Better is to use ng bootstrap or angular material stuffs
 please check https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview   or 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-select/ng-select

a working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qhrskx?file=app%2Fselect-multiple-example.ts

Comment: I have created angular form to store value and I am setting it as null using this.filterForm.get('select').setValue([]); but is not resetting.

Comment: the bootstrap plugin you are using is not for angular. So please choose one which is dedicatedly for angular. for angular, there is ng-bootstrap.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qhrskx?file=app%2Fselect-multiple-example.ts   please check this it's working. here I use from angular material library